# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could not find com.github.BluRe-CN:ComplexView:v1.1

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, github-api, implementation

[pleasecan you help me for this probleme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtRR5.png)

[Could not find com.github.BluRe-CN:ComplexView:v1.1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktCQq.png)

Answer (score 4):

implementation 'com.github.BluRe-CN:ComplexView:v1.1' ❌
implementation 'com.github.BluRe-CN:ComplexView:1.1' ✅